# IntegrityError at /api/users/profile/update

Tags: python, reactjs, django

I am trying to implement an update user functionality but whenever I try to update a user I get back an IntegrityError saying: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

Here's what I have so far:

Those are my serializers for the user:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    _id = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    isAdmin = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', '_id', 'username', 'email', 'name', 'isAdmin']

    def get__id(self, obj):
        return obj.id

    def get_isAdmin(self, obj):
        return obj.is_staff

    def get_name(self, obj):
        name = obj.first_name
        if name == '':
            name = obj.email
        return name


class UserSerializerWithToken(UserSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', '_id', 'username', 'email', 'name', 'isAdmin', 'token']

    def get_token(self, obj):
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(obj)
        return str(token.access_token)
```

Here's my view method:

```py
@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def updateUserProfile(request):
    user = request.user
    serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(user, many=False)
    data = request.data
    user.first_name = data['name']
    user.username = data['email']
    user.email = data['email']

    if data['password'] != '':
        user.password = make_password(data['password'])

    user.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

And this is my user action:

```js
export const updateUserProfile = (user) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_REQUEST,
    });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.access}`,
      },
    };
    const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/users/profile/update`, user, config);
    dispatch({
      type: USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
    localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.detail
          ? error.response.data.detail
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

At Google Chrome inspect it says that the error is being catched at line 142 (at const {data} in the updateUserProfile function). I've read that this error might happen when you try to create a new user with the same credentials(username or email), but in my case I am sending out a put request and I can't understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: In your DB you already have user with username `data['email']`

Comment: @BartoszStasiak I tried to comment out user.username from the view to see if it's gonna work and then I tried to comment out user.email, both ended up with the same error.

Comment: Can you check if error persist if you reset/delete database? (Warning: You will lost data from current database)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you add a full_clean function to validate before saving,

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        return super(UserModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

if you use the default user model then can use this validation in the signal pre-save handler so that it will exit graciously in case of unique constrain validation.

```
@receiver(pre_save)
def pre_save_handler(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.full_clean()
```

Comment: I wil try this solution, but before I do I know it's a bit noob question but where do I declare the override save function ?

Comment: UPDATE: 
I added the pre_save_handler to signals.py and connected it, I assigned the default User model as sender and tried to run the request again but had the same result.

Comment: what is the username you are using? are you using the Django standard user table or custom user table, if so please share the usermodel

Comment: have you printed and checked whether the username field is getting any data?

Comment: try fetching the user obj and then save the user data, you are saving the data in the request,
user_obj = User.object.get(email = request.user.email)
user_obj.username = data['username']
user_obj.email = data['email']
user_obj.save()

Comment: I am using the default user model and whenever I try to for example fetch all of the users, the way I display my data is exactly like the fields in the UserSerializer. In my signals.py file I've made it so the username is always equal to the username (I am following a tutorial on this and that's how it was done there)

Comment: So basically in the updateUserProfile, request.user fetches just the email(or username for that matter)  and request.data fetches a QueryDict of name(first_name),email and password. I will try your comment solution after a while and see what happens.